# About setup Wizard

Tags: 12.04

When I install a program on ubuntu, the installation run on terminal, no setup wizard window is opened. What can I do so that new window will open?

Answer (score 0):

Setup windows exist in Windows(they are basically backdoors to spy on you I consider, though I can't prove)

Ubuntu(or GNU/Linux in general) **does not work with setup wizards, it works with configuration files**

Basically, configuration files(or simply config files) are text files you can edit to customise your software.

For now, I think  the default configurations should be fine for you.

> Note that config files can also be edited **in app**, i.e using GUI.